# Giving a 2/1 creature -2/-2

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Disfigure](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDisfigure%5d) reads:

> Target creature gets -2/-2 until end of turn.

If I used that on [Highland Game](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHighland%20Game%5d), a 2/1 creature, would Highland Game still die?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “still” die? Why would it die if you didn’t cast Disfigure?

Comment: @Gendolkari My powers of mind reading tell me that that's not what the "still" refers to. The actual issue is that the toughness is never exactly 0. My mind reading powers have been wrong before, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A creature that has 0 toughness or less will die the next time any would would get priority.

> 704. State-Based Actions
>
> > 704.5f If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard. Regeneration can’t replace this event.